# What is the relationship between $\int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^af(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

If $\int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$ can be treated as the expected value for the probablity density function $f(x)$ and $x \geq 0$.

what is the relationship between $\int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^af(x)dx$ when $a>0$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a distinction between distribution function and density function. I suppose you want $f$ to be a density function.

Comment: yes, I have changed.

Answer (score 4):

Note that for $a\in(0,1)$ we have that $x^a >x$ when $x\in(0,1)$, and $x^a < x$ when $x>1$, so we can't determine in general an order relation between $\int x f(x)$ and $\int x^a f(x)$ for unknown $f$.

A similar thing happens when $a>1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a density function on $(0,\infty)$ then we have the inequlaities

1) $\int_0^{\infty} x^{a} f(x)\, dx \leq (\int_0^{\infty} x f(x)\, dx)^{a}$ for $0<a<1$ and

2) $\int_0^{\infty} x f(x)\, dx \leq (\int_0^{\infty} x^{a} f(x)\, dx)^{1/a}$ for $a>1$.

Both these follow immediately form Holder's inequality.

But without the powers on the right side the inequalities are false.

Comment: As for the inequality(2), could I write it in this way: $(\int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx)^a \leq \int_{0}^{\infty}x^af(x)dx$

Comment: Yes, that is fine too.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I am not familar with Holder's inequality. In Holder's inequalities, we need $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, but in ours, I donn't find this. Could you give a prove for one of the bove inequlaities, I will apreciate it.

Comment: When $0<a<1$ take $p=\frac 1 a$ and when $a>1$ take $p=a$. In the first case we get $\int x^{a} f(x)\, dx \leq (\int (x^{a})^{p} f(x)\, dx)^{1/p} (\int 1^{q}f(x)\, dx)^{1/q}=\int xf(x)\, dx$. The second case is similar.